# Calling dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() ) inside a NSOperationqueue

Tags: grand-central-dispatch, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I'm performing a few `NSInvocationOperation`s by adding them to a `NSOperationQueue`. While making changes to UI, I call the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() )` instead of `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^(void){}]`. Does this sound logically right? I'm still trying to execute the block on the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right. `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block)` is thread-safe, just putting the block to the main queue, so you can call it from NSOperationQueue or any thread.